# My elements make a blank output (Selenium Python)

Tags: python, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

When I try to print the elements, in Selenium, it makes a blank output.

My code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(input("Link Player: "))

sleep(0.5)
pace = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[contains(@class,'stat')]")
shooting = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Shooting')]/following-sibling::span")
passing = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class='name'][contains(text(),'Passing')]/following-sibling::span") # This element
agility = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class='name'][contains(text(),'Agility')]/following-sibling::span") # This element
defending = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class='name'][contains(text(),'Defending')]/following-sibling::span")# This element
physical = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class='name'][contains(text(),'Physical')]/following-sibling::span")# This element

print(shooting.text) # Only one that works is "pace"
```

And a part of a site: (https://fifarenderz.com/22/player/30900061)

```
<div data-v-b401ba9e="" class="avg-stat"><span data-v-b401ba9e="" class="name">Physical</span> <span data-v-b401ba9e="" class="stat stat-color-great">141</span> <div data-v-b401ba9e="" class="vs-progress--background vs-progress-#35a936" style="background: rgba(53, 169, 54, 0.1); height: 13px;"><div class="vs-progress--foreground" style="background: rgb(53, 169, 54); width: 100.714%;"></div><!----></div></div>
```

Comment: If the `find_element()` calls succeeded (i.e. did not throw an exception), then the elements **were** found.  If the `.text` attribute on those elements is unexpectedly blank, then perhaps you're looking for the wrong elements.

Comment: If the page contains more than one matching element, `find_element()` will return the **first** one.  Perhaps this is your issue?  Perhaps the first matching element on the page actually does have a blank text, and you expected to find some other occurrence of that element?

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is that you use time.sleep. With webscrapers it's very bad to use sleeps, because it can take longer or shorter due to different processes. This means that the page has not fully loaded and the program has already started to evaluate the data. In Selenium there is an extra function that allows you to wait for certain things, in your case the main object where the data is containing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# maybe you dont need to add these options - in my case selenium wont open because of these errors.
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://fifarenderz.com/22/player/30900061")
timeout = 30

WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="w-1/2 md:w-1/3 xxl:w-1/6"]')))
pace = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[contains(@class,'stat')]").text
shooting = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Shooting')]/following-sibling::span").text
passing = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class='name'][contains(text(),'Passing')]/following-sibling::span").text
agility = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class='name'][contains(text(),'Agility')]/following-sibling::span").text
defending = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class='name'][contains(text(),'Defending')]/following-sibling::span").text
physical = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class='name'][contains(text(),'Physical')]/following-sibling::span").text

print("pace: ", pace)
print("shooting: ", shooting)
print("passing: ", passing)
print("agility: ", agility)
print("defending: ", defending)
print("physical: ", physical)
```

this script is waiting until the main element is visible then its going to continue.
thats the output when executing the program:

```
pace:  115
shooting:  74
passing:  107
agility:  109
defending:  157
physical:  141
```

Comment: It gives always a blank output

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://fifarenderz.com/22/player/30900020")
timeout = 30

WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="w-full stat-row"]')))
pace = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[text()='Pace']//following-sibling::span").text
shooting = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                               "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[text()='Shooting']//following-sibling::span").text
passing = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                              "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[text()='Passing']//following-sibling::span").text
agility = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                              "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[text()='Agility']//following-sibling::span").text
defending = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[text()='Defending']//following-sibling::span").text
physical = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                               "//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[text()='Physical']//following-sibling::span").text

print("pace: ", pace)
print("shooting: ", shooting)
print("passing: ", passing)
print("agility: ", agility)
print("defending: ", defending)
print("physical: ", physical)
```

Outputs

```
pace:  138
shooting:  89
passing:  120
agility:  115
defending:  159
physical:  137
```